# How I can solve this differential equation use implicit function theorem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-function-theorem

I have to find the solution of the next differential equation:

$$x'(t)=\frac{-\frac{\partial F(t,x(t))}{\partial t}}{\frac{\partial F(t,x(t))}{\partial x}}$$

I need help I get all mixed up with this problem...

PD: you know $\frac{\partial F(t,x(t))}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{\partial F(t,x(t))}{\partial x}$, thanks!

Comment: $$
x = - \int \frac {\frac {\partial F(t, x(t))}{\partial t}}{\frac {\partial F(t, x(t))}{\partial x}} dt
$$

Comment: I have been thinking how I could I solve this problem, I think that you answer is bad to this problem, because if I said that $ x(t) = - \int \frac {\frac {\partial F(t, x(t))}{\partial t}}{\frac {\partial F(t, x(t))}{\partial x}} dt$ it is, generally, difficult to solve so...

Comment: Actually, my answer is exactly the same as @LutzL's, that you marked as a solution.

Comment: the answer that give LutzL's is a curve who solution satisface the differential equation, your answer is the solution but the solution we can not get in your way

Comment: So, you just replaced fraction with the new function, and called it $f(s, x(s))$ and think they are different? I think I'll stop here, thanks :D

Comment: if you are searching a function $x:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R} \ / \ t\rightarrow \ x(t)$ and you say that $ x(t) = - \int \frac {\frac {\partial F(t, x(t))}{\partial t}}{\frac {\partial F(t, x(t))}{\partial x}} dt$ you dont get nothing, but if you say, like said @LutzL, that $f(t,x(t))=0$ then you get a curve where $x(t)$ is in that curve, so the curve is the implicitly equation of that differential equation

Comment: You should read his answer more carefully. He says $F(t, x(t)) = \text{const}$, which is true, but integrates $f(x, x(t))$, which is defined through IVP $x' = f(t, x(t))$, which in your case is that fraction of fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is the implicit function defined by 
$$
F(t,x(t))=F(t_0,x_0)=const.
$$
in some interval around $t_0$ with values in a neighborhood of $x_0$.

---

Note that for an IVP $x'=f(t,x)$, $x(t_0)=x_0$ the equivalent Picard integral (fixed-point) equation is 
$$
x(t)=x_0+\int_{t_0}^t f(s,x(s))\,ds.
$$ 
Thus not much information is gained as long as the unknown function $x(t)$ also appears inside the integrand.

Comment: ok now, thanks!

Comment: It is maybe worth noting why $F(t,x)=\text{const}$, namely the differential equation can be shown to be exact.